# JAVA: Advance text file to next line by pressing a key

Tags: java, text, keypress

I'm writing a program in Java that will advance the text line by line upon having a key pressed (most likely ENTER). I have the text scanner built and working, but it spits out the entire text file. How would i write a KeyPress event that would result in the text file advancing to the next line?

Here's the text scanner:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class textReader {



public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    try
    {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("ftp.txt");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(fis);
        
        while(sc.hasNextLine()) {
            System.out.println(sc.nextLine());
        }
        sc.close();
        }
    catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could wait for the 'enter' key quite simply, by adding a single line to your while loop:

```
while(sc.hasNextLine()) {
    System.out.println(sc.nextLine());
    System.in.read()
}
```

Answer (score -1):

EDITTED SOLUTION:

---

How about:

```java
     public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner awaitEnter = new Scanner(System.in);
        try {
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("ftp.txt");
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(fileInputStream);

            while(scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                System.out.print(scanner.nextLine());
                awaitEnter.nextLine();// blocks until user hits enter
            }
            scanner.close();

        } catch(IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Check file exists???");
        }
        awaitEnter.close();
    }
```

Comment: Closing your scanner closes the stream. KeyListener isn't for command line stuff, that'd be for swing apps. The exception handling in this snippet is silly ('e.printStackTrace()' as the sole entry in the body of a catch block is a grave error, even if it is common. Lets stop perpetuating it.

Comment: Not here to do a code review - soz, not soz. Noted on KeyListener - removed. Admittedly I didn't test my solution but there's enough of a clue to make it work :) I've now tested the solution based on your feedback and updated my solutioin (which works for me). Considering this looks more like an introductory assignment I'm not too worried about throwing a correct exception back up the call-stack and having it handled correctly. Also SO doesn't reward for such comments so I keep my answers minimal.

Comment: Thanks Rob, that's what I was trying to figure out. I had done some work and figured out the .nextLine() method. You've seemingly confirmed what I found!

Comment: @JordanGarrett - pls upvote + mark as correct if it works for you and we both get points